# remove an specific typo after first and last appearance

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose the next dataframe:

```
#  code                                            countries
#1 A001 [[Germany, China, Japan], [Chile, Mexico], [Poland]]
#2 A002     [[], [Japan], [Singapore, Indonesia, Micronesia]]
#3 A003       [[Tuvalu, Chile], [], [North Macedonia, Sweden]]
```

How could I remove all `[` after its firts appareance and all `]` before last appareance?

In a way thtat dataframe could look like this:

```
   code countries
#1 A001 [Germany, China, Japan, Chile, Mexico, Poland]
#2 A002     [Japan, Singapore, Indonesia, Micronesia]
#3 A003       [Tuvalu, Chile, North Macedonia, Sweden]
```

### data

```
df <- data.frame(code=c('A001', 'A002', 'A003'),
                 countries=c('[[Germany, China, Japan], [Chile, Mexico], [Poland]]',
                             '[[], [Japan], [Singapore, Indonesia, Micronesia]]',
                             '[[Tuvalu, Chile], [], [North Macedonia, Sweden]]')
                )
```

Comment: Easy option is `map_chr(str_extract_all(df$countries, "\\w+"), ~ sprintf("[%s]", toString(.x)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`:

Here, I wrapped `gsub()` in `paste()`. The `regex` expression is finding anything in `countries` that starts with `^` a bracket `[` or ends with `$` a bracket `]`. A great explanation of the `*SKIP` and `*FAIL` control verbs (and thereby the rest of the `regex` statement in `gsub()` lives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) and is more cordial than I can probably articulate.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(countries = paste("[",gsub("(^\\[|\\]$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([][])", "", countries), "]" , sep = ""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method using `regex` in `base R`

```
df$countries <- gsub("(?<=\\[),\\s*|(?<=\\,)\\s+,", "", 
    gsub("(^\\[|\\]$)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([][])", "", df$countries, perl = TRUE), perl = TRUE)
df$countries
#[1] "[Germany, China, Japan, Chile, Mexico, Poland]" 
#[2] "[Japan, Singapore, Indonesia, Micronesia]"    
#[3]  "[Tuvalu, Chile, North Macedonia, Sweden]"
```

---

Or another option is to extract the words and then `paste` them together

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df$countries <- map_chr(str_extract_all(df$countries, "\\w+"), 
     ~ sprintf("[%s]", toString(.x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `regmatches` + `toString` + `sprintf`

```
transform(
    df,
    countries = sprintf(
        "[%s]",
        sapply(
            regmatches(countries, gregexpr("(\\w+\\s?)+", countries)),
            toString
        )
    )
)
```

gives

```
  code                                      countries
1 A001 [Germany, China, Japan, Chile, Mexico, Poland]
2 A002      [Japan, Singapore, Indonesia, Micronesia]
3 A003       [Tuvalu, Chile, North Macedonia, Sweden]
```